# Using a time comparison to control event triggers

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms application that will trigger an email alert and a database entry when the input from a humidity sensor is over a certain threshold. The problem I have once an alarm is sent, it will continue to send alarms for as long as the value is over the threshold. My goal is to essentially set a cool down for for the alarm so it waits for a minute before sending another alarm. I decided to use a time comparison to check if an alarm had been sent before one minute but I'm having trouble placing the variables in the correct places in my code to run the loop. Here is my code:

```
if (theID == 11)
{
   templabel.Text = thetemp.ToString();
   humilabel.Text = thehumi.ToString();
   now = DateTime.Now;
   int id1 = 2234543;
   string alarm_description1 = "Warning: Humidity";
   int ct1 = 78;
   string hmm1 = "10/50";
   if (later.Subtract(now) >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) && thehumi > 50)
   {
       try
       {
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id1);
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alarmtype", alarm_description1);
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", now);
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", where);
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tempmm", tmm);
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temp", ct1);
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@humimm", hmm1);
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@humi", thehumi);
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", stat);
         myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
         this.test_panelTableAdapter.Fill(this.mynewdataDataSet.test_panel);
         //e-mail
         later = DateTime.Now;
         MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
         msg.From = new MailAddress("autobahnalertsystem@gmail.com");
         msg.To.Add("xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
         msg.Subject = "Alert:Humidity";
         msg.Body = "Unit 1: Temperature/Humidity has detected excessive humidity.";

         SmtpClient smt = new SmtpClient();
         smt.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
         System.Net.NetworkCredential ntcd = new NetworkCredential();
         ntcd.UserName = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
         ntcd.Password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
         smt.Credentials = ntcd;
         smt.EnableSsl = true;
         smt.Port = 587;
         smt.Send(msg);
         warninglabel.Text = "4";
         MessageBox.Show("Alarm Sent!");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
       finally
       {
         conn.Close();
       }

    }
}
```

How can I place my time variables in the correct place to run my loop without any errors such that after the first alarm trigger it will wait another minute before sending another alarm? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo the `later` variable is initialized in the section of the code where the email is sent.

Comment: Okay, what about the declaration? Where do you declare `DateTime later`? I think it should be declared as a class field.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo Good point, Ill declare it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that your `later` value will never surpass the `now` value, i.e.

```
later <= now
```

will always be true.

Now let's see this line:

> `later.Subtract(now) >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)`

This line is equivalent to `later - now >= ...`. But remember the first rule above, your `later` can be less than `now`, thus this subtraction will never resulted in positive value. It will be either zero or negative.

To fix this, you need to **either**:

1. Swap the `later` and `now`, thus becoming `now.Subtract(later)`, or `(now - later)`. **or**
2. Change the right-hand side comparison, i.e. `later.Subtract(now) <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-1)`. Notice the `<=` and negative value `-1`.

You can see documentation about `Subtract` method in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I'll rearrange my variables. Now the problem is that the alarm won't trigger for the first time because of the time comparison check. How would I allow it to launch the alarm if the humidity value goes over the threshold and after this is done check the time difference before it sends another alarm?

Comment: @AnthonyChavez Initialize or declare `later` with 'very small` value, i.e. `private DateTime later = DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Once I followed your earlier advice to declare them as class fields, I had no problems and it worked as it should. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

some pseudo code but this can be done quite simple just showing design.

```
golbal static bool alarmSet=true;

 public main()    // or inside some button press 
 {
   Task task = new Task(new Action(Guard());
   task.Start();  // notice tasks ends when alarmset = False
 }


private void Guard()
{ while (alarmSet)
{
  d = detecthumidity.value;
  if (d > trigger) { sendEmail();Sleep(60000);} //only sleeps when smoke is detect but will continously check
  sleep(100); //maybe your sensor needs some rest time as well. (like arduino DAC)

}
}
```

while alarmset can be put in a Task or in an object and turn on on Init.

Comment: This makes sense, the only problem I have that is that my UI will be unresponsive for that time and I still want to be able to navigate the form.

Comment: thats why you can put it in a Task, so it runs inside another thread.
Here some ideas for that. 
https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/
Another button can be used to set var alarmSet to false

Comment: Excellent, I'll take a look at that. This is more scalable solution than the one i'm implementing I think.

Comment: added task might contain minor typos didnt use visual studio here.
Also i advice to write sendmail in a separate function so you get cleaner code.